# How to call and execute a Oracle stored procedure using TYPE as a parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

**This is the package specification:**

```
PROCEDURE Save_Countries
    ( p_inst_id Number,
      p_CountryList  IN T_COUNTRY_TYPE
    )
AS
v_count number;
BEGIN
            for i in p_CountryList.first..p_CountryList.last loop

                  insert into countries (INST_ID, COUNTRY_NAME, COUNTRY_CODE)
                        values (p_inst_id, p_CountryList(i).COUNTRY_NAME, p_CountryList(i).COUNTRY_CODE);
            end loop;
      Commit;
end Save_Countries ;
```

**This is the Type specification:**

```
create or replace TYPE OBJ_COUNTRY FORCE as OBJECT (
      COUNTRY_ID        NUMBER(10),
      COUNTRY_NAME      VARCHAR2(255),
      COUNTRY_CODE      VARCHAR2(6)
);
create or replace TYPE T_COUNTRY_TYPE as TABLE OF OBJ_COUNTRY;
```

**So far I have this:**

```
DECLARE
  P_INST_ID NUMBER;
  P_COUNTRYLIST T_COUNTRY_TYPE;
BEGIN
  P_INST_ID := 255;

  PKG_TEST.SAVE_COUNTRIES(
    P_INST_ID => P_INST_ID,
    P_COUNTRYLIST => P_COUNTRYLIST
  );
END;
```

**Question**
I am trying to call the store procedure from my Oracle SQL Developer. How I can initialize the list (TYPE) so I can pass that as a parameter. I've googled around but I wasn't able to find something to help with this.

Comment: There are several documents about working with collections and initialization on the internet - this one for example: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-collections...
`Code Listing 1:` has the syntax you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nested tables, you must initialise and assign elements to the collection.

```
DECLARE
  P_INST_ID NUMBER;
  P_COUNTRYLIST T_COUNTRY_TYPE := T_COUNTRY_TYPE(); --initialization
BEGIN
  P_INST_ID     := 255;
  P_COUNTRYLIST.extend(2); --allocate 2 null elements.
  P_COUNTRYLIST(1) :=  OBJ_COUNTRY(1,'INDIA','IND'); --set the values
  P_COUNTRYLIST(2) :=  OBJ_COUNTRY(2,'AUSTRALIA','AUS');
--To assign n more elements, use P_COUNTRYLIST.extend(n);



  PKG_TEST.SAVE_COUNTRIES(
    P_INST_ID => P_INST_ID,
    P_COUNTRYLIST => P_COUNTRYLIST
  );
END;
/
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cb625e1b5b40142a4934931c473969a9)

Comment: thanks it worked. It was working with my java code but I wanted to be able to run the same suing the SQL console.